# CLBeacon proximity always returning only .near and .far value but not .immediate

Tags: swift, cllocation, beacon, ios12

I am using estimote beacons for an iOS app and implemented **CLLocationManager** delegate method **didRangeBeacons** to determine the proximity of each beacon.

Based on the **.immediate, .near, .far** proximities, i have some functionalities written.

This was working perfectly before in iOS 11. After iOS 12 upgrade **.immediate** proximity is not at all getting called. Only **.near and .far** is getting called.

I searched a lot and couldn't find any solution for this. What could be the reason for not detecting **.immediate** alone even if i place the iPhone just above the beacon?

Answer (score 0):

Check to see what the `CLBeacon` accuracy field returns.  This is an estimated distance in meters, derived from RSSI and the measured power calibration value configured into the beacon.  Basically, you will get an `.immediate` proximity if the accuracy is 0.5 meters or less.  And you only get an accuracy of 0.5 or less if the RSSI (measured in dBm) is significantly stronger (less negative) than the measured power calibration value (also measured in dBm) configured into the beacon.

You may be able to get your device to return an `.immediate` value by adjusting the measured power calibration value configured into the beacon to be a more negative number.

The above suggestion of course, will not help it work the same way across both iOS 11 and iOS 12 if you really see that there is a difference between the two.  I would be curious to hear if you can reproduce this difference with a second device.

Comment: Can you please let me know how to set measured power calibration value for an estimote beacon?

Comment: Good question!  I'm not an Estimote expert, but that should be an easy question to get answered on their support site.